# How to reduce spacing/padding/margin of the text inside QDoubleSpinBox or QSpinBox to zero?

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

Using Qt 4.8. I would like to set the space between the text of a QSpinBoxes/QDoubleSpinBoxes and the right border of the widget to zero. The left one of the following images is what I got, the right one is what I want:

[image]

Note that I use setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons) to remove the up/down arrows.

The spinboxes are styled using QSS where I can set:

- The padding of the QSpinBox/QDoubleSpinBox to 0px.
- The padding, the margin and the border of the QLineEdit inside the spinbox to 0px.
- I have also created a custom QProxyStyle for the QLineEdit but I'm not able to find any related pixel metric enum that I can use to reduce the space
- I can also try to mess around with the internal QLineControl class which is not possible without fiddling inside Qt's code base. (I have not tried this yet!)